# How to use regex in if-statement in shell script? ( transformation from bash script to regular shell script)

Tags: bash, sh

I've been writing a script with `#!/bin/bash` shebang for a school project but I found out few hours ago that the shebang has to be `#!/bin/sh`. Could you advise me how to format the second if-condition so it would be compatible for every shell script?

```
if [[ -z $date ]]; then
   echo "No date argument"
   exit 1
elif [[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
   return
```

Comment: Actually, it is best to write `if [ -z "$date" ]`: if `$date` is really empty, without double quotes it will fail. And there is no need of double brackets in this comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep.

Replace

```
[[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
```

with

```
echo "$date" | grep -q -E '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
```

or use

```
echo "$date" | egrep '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$' >/dev/null
```